# Suppress Overset text alert for InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, cs6

Is there anyway I can set up a rule to not allow overset text in a text frame? I want to print without getting the "Overset text" alert for an specific text frame.

Comment: Delete the text. Add a text frame off the page and let your text flow into that....

Answer (score 1):

Object → Text Frame Options → Auto-Size (tab) → Auto-Sizing = Height Only (or both)

This solves your issue.

If you want hide a part of the text, just put it into a frame (Paste Into). This frame became a mask for a text box.

You can setup such behavior for any new text box as default. This can be done from 'Objects Styles' panel.

[image]
[image: Text Frame option (Indesign)]
[image]